# How do I add an existing bitbucket SSH account to Xcode 9?

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, xcode9

I need to access a local bitbucket server account using SSH. I previously used SourceTree to retrieve the project, but now I want the ability to push and pull from Xcode.

How do I add this account to Xcode?

Comment: I found a way to clone the project using Xcode, which accomplishes what I need. Useful answer was here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/xcode-for-bitbucket-server-951406028.html

Answer (score 0):

SSH isn't limited to Sourcetree, at least not in macOS. If you already have the SSH key on that system then you should already be able to connect to Bitbucket with it. If that SSH key isn't on that system, then you can create a new one with `ssh-keygen` and add the public key to your Bitbucket account.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9 does not support adding a Bitbucket account to its list of accounts, but Xcode 10 does. One solution is to move to Xcode 10.

If you still want to use Xcode 9, remember that you don't have to add a Bitbucket account to Xcode to use Bitbucket with Xcode. You already created a remote branch for your project in SourceTree. All you need to do is add the remote in Xcode.

Open Xcode's source control navigator by choosing View > Navigators > Show Source Control Navigator.

[image]

Since you already created a remote branch, that branch may already be in the Remotes folder. If that's the case you don't have to do anything else to push and pull from Xcode. If the branch is not there, right-click the Remotes folder and choose Add Existing Remote. A sheet will open asking for the location of the remote. Supply the location of your Bitbucket repository.